# Easy way to enter conventional forms of limit expression?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, formatting, input, traditional-form

(1) I want to insert into a Text cell conventional *in-line* mathematical notation like $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$.

I know I can do it by typing the StandardForm `Limit[f[x], x -> a]` in an Input cell, convert to Traditional Form via a Cell menu item, then paste the result into the Text cell. Or, per comment by @Bob Hanlon, type it into the text cell, select it, and use Evaluation menu item "Evaluate in place".

Is there some quicker way to do that, by means of a keyboard sequence or palette?

[I looked at the Classroom Assistant palette, but there seems to be no button to enter a limit expression other than in StandardForm (which is a bit strange, given the buttons in that palette for entering traditional forms for sums, products, derivatives, and integrals).]

(2) What about the conventional *display* mathematical notation like $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$
where the $x \to a$ is *below* the $\lim$ part?

Is there some reasonably easy way to get that?

Comment: You can at least do `Limit[f[x], x -> a] // TraditionalForm`, but as for pasting into a Text cell, I don't know.

Comment: After entering the expression `Limit[f[x], x -> a] // TraditionalForm` in the text cell, select the expression and from the `Evaluation` menu select `Evaluate in Place`

Comment: Using `TraditionalForm` like that works OK -- but *only* for an "in-line" limit layout, that is, with the $x\to a$ in subscript position to the right of $\lim$. How can I get  $x\to a$ to appear *below" $\lim$, as in a proper display-math layout -- the way I showed in my original question?

Comment: I usually do it the "shortcut" way: in a Text Cell, press **Ctrl** + **9**, enter `lim`, press **Ctrl** + **4**, enter `a->0`, press **→**, enter `sin(a)`.

Comment: Entering `a -> 0` or such as a subscript, with shortcut key Ctrl+4, only allows the "in-line" layout for limits, but not the proper "display" layout for limits in a display.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach is to use the Option Inspector (menu command Format > OptionInspector) to set the option for the relevant cells

```
UnderscriptBoxOptions -> {LimitsPositioning -> False}
```

If I'm doing this a lot, I might create a new style that inherits from `"Text"`, or change `"Text"` itself (e.g., via a private stylesheet).

Or one can create a template of sorts, for copy-pasting, with the following:

```
CellPrint@Cell[TextData[{

 Cell[BoxData[
  FormBox[
   StyleBox[
    RowBox[{
      UnderscriptBox["lim",
       RowBox[{"\[Placeholder]", "\[Rule]", "\[Placeholder]"}]], 
      " ",
      "\[Placeholder]"}],
    UnderscriptBoxOptions -> {LimitsPositioning -> False}], 
   TraditionalForm]
  ]], 

 " "}], "Text"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

One could also create one's own palette with a button to paste one's own commonly used text constructions.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the "InlineCell" style definition. For example:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["InlineCell"], ScriptLevel->0, FontFamily->"Times"]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

Now, when creating an inline cell in a text cell, the above "InlineCell" options will be used. In the "InlineCell", you can either:

1. Enter the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm) of an expression and then use the `Cell | Convert To | TraditionalForm` menu item, or the equivalent keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in OSX) to transform the cell into [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm)
2. Enter the desired output using the usual keyboard short cuts.

Here is an animation showing both approaches:

[image]